# SQLiteでINNER JOIN してUPDATEさせるには

Tags: sql, sqlite

お世話になります。

ごく基本的なことで申し訳ありません。

SQLiteにて、三つのテーブルのデータを一度に更新したいので、
INNER JOIN で結合してUPDATEしようとしましたが、悉くエラーが出ました。
何度も見直したのですが、『構文エラー』と言われてしまいました。

```
UPDATE person SET a.name='初日の出' FROM  ((person as a INNER JOIN bloodtype as b ON a.cid=b.cid) INNER JOIN student_data as c ON a.cid=c.cid) WHERE a.id=1
↑構文エラーがありました。"."

UPDATE ((person as a INNER JOIN bloodtype as b ON a.cid=b.cid) INNER JOIN student_data as c ON a.cid=c.cid) SET a.name='初日の出' WHERE a.id=1
↑構文エラーがありました。"("
```

上記の様な感じなのですが、おかしな点がありましたら、ご指摘ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

更新するテーブルに対して`JOIN`はできないようです。

英語版に同様の質問がありますので、そちらも参照してください。
[How do I make an UPDATE while joining tables on SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite)

```
UPDATE person
   SET name = '初日の出'
 WHERE id = 1
   AND cid IN (
 SELECT b.cid
   FROM bloodtype b
  INNER JOIN student_data c
     ON (b.cid = c.cid));
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
すみません。自分のSQLを見直しましたが、これじゃ結合する意味が全くありません。変更する値を、personのnameだけでなく、bのbtype、student_dataのshintyouと行いたい場合はどうすれば良いでしょう。いただいたサンプルは確かに動きましたが、b,cともに変更をさせる場合をお願いいたします。

それと、INNER JOUNのUPDATEができないのは、『SQLiteでは』ということですか？他のMySQLやpostgresqlとかでは可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: `UPDATE`は一つのテーブルに対して更新するので、テーブルごとに`UPDATE`文を実行することになります。`MySQL`は`JOIN`できます。

Comment: @たたぱた [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/update.html)ではupdate時にjoin句が使えます。[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.5/html/sql-update.html)ではwhere句で結合します。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
ネットで検索すると、できるとかは書いてあったのですが、SQLiteではできるかどうかが解りませんでした。
おかげですっきりしました。